# Checked the Checkboxes that is already checked

Tags: android, customdialog

I have one EditText (edModelColor). when user click on edModelColor(EditText) then the custom dialog will be called.Custom dialog consist of RecylerView and searchview and one custom row for each item. Custom row contains ImageView(icon), TextView (colorNames) and checkbox for selection. When user click on any checkbox I passed the colorName and its position in adapter into method checkAndRemove. this method will add or remove the color name according to its adapter position and the colorNames will added into edModelColor(EditText). its working fine but the problem is that once the user click on edModelColor(EditText) again, I want to checked those checkboxes which are already checked inside CustomDialogbox.I have seen some articles online but I could not understand what they meant.

bodyColorDialog:

```
    private void bodyColorDialog() {

    TextView txtClose;
    TextView tvCancel;
    Button btnOk;

    bodyColorDialog.setContentView(R.layout.ed_body_color_dialog);
    bodyColorDialog.setCancelable(false);

    txtClose = bodyColorDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtModelClose);
    tvCancel = bodyColorDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvCancel);
    btnOk = bodyColorDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

    edBodyColorSearchView = bodyColorDialog.findViewById(R.id.edBodyColorSearchViewColor);

    edBodyColorRecylerView = bodyColorDialog.findViewById(R.id.edBodyColorRecylerView);
    edBodyColorRecylerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    bodyColorArrayList.clear();
    setUpBodyColorArrayList();

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            selectionCMap = new HashMap<>();
            selectionCMap = edBodyColorAdapter.selectionColorsMap;


            for(String value : selectionCMap.values()){
               /* tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n" + value);*/

                edBodyColor.append(value + ",");
            }
            bodyColorDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    txtClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bodyColorDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    tvCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bodyColorDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    bodyColorDialog.show();
}

   private void setUpBodyColorArrayList() {

    bodyColorArrayList.clear();

    String bodyColorName[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.body_color_array);
    int bodyColorIcons[] = {R.drawable.red, R.drawable.black, R.drawable.violet, R.drawable.white,
            R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.green, R.drawable.yello};

    for(int i =0; i < bodyColorIcons.length; i++)
    {
        bodyColorArrayList.add(new edModelBodyColor(bodyColorName[i], bodyColorIcons[i]));
    }

    edBodyColorAdapter = new edBodyColorAdapter(getContext(), bodyColorArrayList);
    edBodyColorRecylerView.setAdapter(edBodyColorAdapter);



    edBodyColorSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String queryString) {


            edBodyColorAdapter.getFilter().filter(queryString);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String queryString) {

            edBodyColorAdapter.getFilter().filter(queryString);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

edBodyColorAdapter.java

```
        holder.checkBoxColor.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

                int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                clickedColorNamePosition = edBodyColorArrayList.indexOf(filteredArrayList.get(position));
                String name = edBodyColorArrayList.get(clickedColorNamePosition).getBodyColorName();

                Toast.makeText(context, "name = " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //this mthod will check if selected checkbox value is already present or not.
            // It present then remove ( means user unchecked box) and if value is not there means user has selected checkbox
                checkAndRemove(position,name);

        }

    });
```

checkAndRemove:

```
   private void checkAndRemove(int position, String name) {

    if(selectionColorsMap.containsKey(position)){
        selectionColorsMap.remove(position);
        Toast.makeText(context, "removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        selectionColorsMap.put(position, name);
        Toast.makeText(context, "added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

preview:
 [image]

Conculusion: I want to check these checkboxes values when user click again on edBodyColor dialog..

Answer (score 0):

I as can see, you are initializing the ArrayList of colors every time you are showing the dialog, that's why, you start always at initial state.

Instead, you should initialized the ArrayList inside `onCreate()` and reuse it every time to maintain the previous state.